# Magento local installation issue with link of item menu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, link, localhost

i have a problem about link of item menu of my site in Magento. I have transferred my site from remote to local.

But when i click on a menu button, the link goes to the online site and no locally. Why this? Where can i go for edit the link for the redirect?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you put any hard code for menu or if you use any menu extension check with that link

Comment: did you delete the `var/cache` folder and change the  `base url`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a test environment in your machine, try the following steps:

1. Export your live DB
2. Import it in your local machine

Go in to the `core_config_data` table and change the 'value' of:

```
 web/unsecure/base_url
```

And:

```
web/secure/base_url
```

To:

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

Go in to:

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

And change the username and password to the correct ones

And if the previous step doesn't help delete everything in the 'var' folder